# Best option between use of onerror vs srcset when using svg in img tag?

Tags: html, css, image, svg, png

What will be the best option to use between:

onerror:

```
<img src="my.svg" onerror="this.src='my.png'" />
```

srcset:

```
<img src="my.png" srcset="my.svg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The srcset is [not supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=srcset) in most of the browsers. And for this reason, I may suggest you to use `onerror`.

If you're not worried about older browsers, then I may suggest you to use `srcset`.

Thus, it's totally up to you what you choose.

---

**Edit:** You may use it like below:

```
<img src="my.svg" srcset="my.svg" onerror="this.src='my.png'" />
```

This works like:

```
Is srcset supported?

Yes: Is svg supported?

   Yes: Use it.

   No: Check src. See below option with "No".

No: Is svg supported?

   Yes: Use it.

   No: Use onerror image.
```